# Smarty:How can Use Php code get the foreach's variable

Tags: php, foreach, smarty

My Code:

```
 <!--    {foreach from=$goods_cat.cat_id item=rec_cat name=f1}-->

       <?php      
         **echo  $rec_cat[id]; // get nothing, why?**
        $smarty->assign('goods_cat_' . $rec_cat[id], assign_cat_goods($rec_cat[id], 4));
        $smarty ->assign('cat_goods_nf' , 'goods_cat_' . $rec_cat[id]);           
?>
     <!--{foreach from=$cat_goods_nf item=goods}-->
                  {$goods.url}
     <!--{/foreach}--> 

  <!--{/foreach}-->
```

I need the id of  rec_cat ,so I use PHP Tags to get it,but Its display nothing? why ?How can I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `<?php` tag inside a template, but instead use `{php}` tag of Smarty :

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/fr/language.function.php.tpl

Then you get your variables just like so :

```
$var = $this->get_template_vars('var');
```